# How do I use the ASP.NET grid view to instert new records?

Tags: asp.net, html, windows, database

Using the ASP.NET grid view. It displays 3 columns with 1 row for each, displaying an integer saved in the database. I would like to have a text input one for each column, so the user can add a new row of integers to the database. (The table only displays the last row updated, that part seems to be working OK)

Here is the code I have that displays data but without the input option I would like.

What is the way this is done in ASP.NET (3.5)? Are there more options in the control or do I need to manually bring in text input controls and give each one manual code to update the database? Any help is appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know the asp.net website? There are a lot of tutorials, e.g. about [data access](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/data). You might find the information you need, e.g [An Overview of Inserting, Updating, and Deleting Data](http://www.asp.net/learn/data-access/tutorial-16-cs.aspx).

Also check out the ASP.NET Dynamic Data section on the same page.